# Solve the recurrence relation : $f(n) = 1 + \frac{f(n) + f(n-1) + \cdots + f(1)}{n+1}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

For naturals $n$, $f(n) = 1 + \dfrac{f(n) + f(n-1) + \cdots + f(1)}{n+1}$. What is $f(n)$? This is not a homework problem. Is there a general method to solve these recurrence relations? I will appreciate if someone directs me to a short tutorial/book to learn about solving recurrence relations.

Comment: Just to be certain before people start attempting to solve this: on the left-hand side of the equals sign it's supposed to be $f(n)$ and not $f(n+1)$?

Comment: Yes the left hand side is $f(n)$, i didn't want the relation to look cumbersome. Besides this is the way I discovered it.

Comment: Do you have a condition for $f(1)$ or some base case in mind?

Comment: If you put $n=1$, in the equation you get $f(1)=2$. This is the base case

Comment: How about $f(n) = 1 + H_n$, where $H_n$ is a harmonic number?

Comment: Hint: Rearrange to $nf(n) = n + 1 + f(1) + \dots + f(n-1)$. Now write the same relation for $(n-1)f(n-1)$ and subtract. You end up with the recurrence relation $f(n) - f(n-1) = 1/n$, which telescopes.

Comment: @stochasticboy321, Your answer is very neat and elegant. I used generating function method, but it is a way longer.

Comment: thats too broad to be taken from all sides, but you can try power series or finding roots [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)

Answer (score 1):

In a matrix-scheme the given equality looks like
$$ \small \begin{array}{} 
 \; & &\begin{array} {|r|} 1\\f(1)\\f(2)\\f(3)\\ \vdots \end{array} \\
 & * & \\
  \begin{array} {r|rrrrr|}  &  1 \\ 
             \phantom{f(1)} &  1 & 1/2 \\
             \phantom{f(1)} &  1 & 1/3 & 1/3\\
             \phantom{f(1)} &  1 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4\\
                            & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\\
  \end{array} 
 & = & 
  \begin{array} {|r|} 1\\f(1)\\f(2)\\f(3)\\ \vdots \end{array} \\
\end{array}$$
The sequence is obviously the normed eigenvector with the eigenvalue 1 of the bottom-left matrix.

The eigenvector (thus the solution for your function at positive integers) begins then with
$[1,2,5/2!,17/3!,74/4!,...]$ which means $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=2.5$ etc.

I just found a good explanation for the general term, I've got with the (unsigned) Stirlingnumbers first kind as sequence $s_{1:r,2}=\{0,1,3,11,50,274,...\}_{r \ge 0}$
 $$f(k) =_{k \ge 0} 1+ s_{1:k,2}/k! \qquad \qquad f(0)=1$$

Looking at this in terms of generating-functions we find that
$$ g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k) x^k \qquad \underset {|x| \lt 1}{=} \qquad {1\over1-x} +  {-\log(1-x) \over 1-x}  $$

---

Remark: the matrix-ansatz proved useful for me in many instances, so I think it's often useful to approach similar problems with this method (of course only when a simpler one runs into the void...). A very well known example where a recursion is handled (and indepth studied) by the matrix-method is the Fibonacci-sequence, and that matrix-solution leads then also very naturally to a Binet-type formula. If you are interested in more examples you can find some other answers of mine here in MSE. For the matrix-method with the Fibonacci sequence there is very nice and exhaustive material at [Rob Johnsons's website](http://community.dur.ac.uk/bob.johnson/fibonacci/).

Answer (score -1):

### Not an answer...

Let $f_n = f(n)$. Then 
$$ f(n) = 1 + \dfrac{f(n) + f(n-1) + \cdots + f(1)}{n+1} \\ 
f_n = n+1+ \frac{f_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i}{n+1} \\ 
n f_n + f_n = n+1 + f_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i \\
nf_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i + n +1 \\
f_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i + n +1}{n}\\
f_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i +1}{n} + 1.
$$

That might be more useful for some approaches.